# Не изменяются данные в реестре в ветке Windows NT

Tags: c#, реестр

Пробую записать данные в реестр. Данный код срабатывает почти в любой ветке, кроме Windows NT. Что не так с кодом?

```
  var key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Font Management");

  key.SetValue("Setting1", "This is our setting 1");
  key.SetValue("Setting2", "This is our setting 2");
  key.Close();
```

Comment: А почему у вас путь начинается с `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`? Вы ж стартуете уже с `Registry.CurrentUser`.

Comment: поправил, но суть не меняется

Comment: А есть ли у вашего кода административные права? Если нет, может быть, вы сталкиваетесь с [Registry Virtualization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530198.aspx)?